# React state is always undefined when invoke onClick event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, setstate, react-functional-component

So I have the following code:

```
export default function Component() {  
  
  const [list, setList] = useState<JSX.Element[]>();
  const [active, setActive] = useState<JSX.Element>();


  useEffect(()=>{
    let startTab = <li key={"0000-0000-0000-0000"} onClick={() => onClick()}>Star 1</li>;
    let secondTab = <li key={"0001-0000-0000-0000"} onClick={() => onClick()}>Star 2</li>;

    setList(() => [startTab, secondTab]);
    setActive(() => startTab);
  },[])

  const onClick= () =>{
    console.log(list)
  }

  return (
    <div id="BodyMain" className={css["Body-container"]}>
      <div className={css["tab-header"]}>
        { (
          <ul className={css["navs"]}>
            {list?.map(tabItem => tabItem)}
          </ul>)
        }
      </div>
      <div className={css["tab-body"]}>{}</div>
    </div> 
  );
}
```

every time I invoke onClick function it just returns undefined!

[image: Screenshot from the console shows that no matter how many times I invoke the function, the value always is undefined!]

Nevertheless, 'React Developer Tools' shows that indeed these states have values!!

[image]

I am unable to change the state from onClick function because it is always undefined. What did I do wrong? and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you try to put `onClick` function definition before `useEffect`?

Comment: @valerii15298 I don't think that would be a problem. But I tried, nothing happened.

Comment: @AaditeyNair I have set the list state with useEffect. The list items are already rendered and the debugging tool shows that the value of the state has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way that you use useEffect() hook.
When you dnt have any dependencies, that hook is gonna run once. Hence  setList(() => [startTab, secondTab]); just runs once

If you want to update it whenever you click, you can add a dependency for the useEffect() hook:

```
const [list, setList] = useState<JSX.Element[]>();
const [active, setActive] = useState<JSX.Element>();
const [ count, setCount ] = useState (0);

useEffect(()=>{
  let startTab = <li key={"0000-0000-0000-0000"} onClick={() => onClick()}>Star 1</li>;
  let secondTab = <li key={"0001-0000-0000-0000"} onClick={() => onClick()}>Star 2</li>;

  setList(() => [startTab, secondTab]);
  setActive(() => startTab);
},[count])

const onClick= () =>{
  setCount(() => count+1)
  console.log(list)
}
```

I usually use a count variable to capture any change and set it as a useEffect dependency.

Read more at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thank you so much @Nam ... I think it works now, however, not in the first click though. I understand because setState is async. but how would you solve it? kindly check the following [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-tu-u7hux?file=/src/Component.js)

Comment: You need to click on the list item to get the function invoked. Open the console within code sandbox to see the output

Answer (score 2):

It happens because during first render `list` is undefined. And `useEffect`
captures `onClick` function with list as undefined. Since useEffect runs only once - list inside onClick will be always undefined. But if useEffect will run,
list will be updated too inside useEffect. And as @nam-h-nguyen said , really with `count` as a dependency useEffect will rerun and hence new value of list will be captured.

Comment: Correct, thank you so much valerii

Comment: This should be the correct answer! React manages state of your component taking snapshot of state variables for each render. Read https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is another solution for that

```
 const [list, setList] = useState<JSX.Element[]>();
 const [active, setActive] = useState<JSX.Element>();
 const [ count, setCount ] = useState (0);
 let startTab = <li key={"0000-0000-0000-0000"} onClick={() => 
    onClick()}>Star 1</li>;
 let secondTab = <li key={"0001-0000-0000-0000"} onClick={() => 
    onClick()}>Star 2</li>;

 useEffect(()=>{
      setList(() => [startTab, secondTab]);
      setActive(() => startTab);
    },[])
  
 const onClick= () =>{
      setList(() => [startTab, secondTab]);
      console.log(list)
    }
```

What I did was:

- I took startTab and seconTab out of the useEffect() hook and made them as global variables for that component so that I can use them everywhere inside that component.
- Then, I just needed to update the "list" directly inside the onClick() function.
- And I used useEffect without a dependency to update the list during the first render.

I like to do this way more than putting everything in the useEffect hook() because anything you put inside it becomes a local variable of it and you cant use it outside of the useEffect() hook.